# What is the regular expression to allow uppercase/lowercase (alphabetical characters), periods, spaces and dashes only?

Tags: regex

I am having problems creating a regex validator that checks to make sure the input has uppercase or lowercase alphabetical characters, spaces, periods, underscores, and dashes only.  Couldn't find this example online via searches. For example:

These are ok:

```
Dr. Marshall
sam smith
.george con-stanza .great
peter.
josh_stinson
smith _.gorne
```

Anything containing other characters is not okay. That is numbers, or any other symbols.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `^[A-Za-z.\s_-]+$`

- `^` asserts that the regular expression must match at the beginning of the subject
- `[]` is a character class - any character that matches inside this expression is allowed
- `A-Z` allows a range of uppercase characters
- `a-z` allows a range of lowercase characters
- `.` matches a period
  rather than a range of characters
- `\s` matches whitespace (spaces and tabs)
- `_` matches an underscore
- `-` matches a dash (hyphen); we have it as the last character in the character class so it doesn't get interpreted as being part of a character range. We could also escape it (`\-`) instead and put it anywhere in the character class, but that's less clear
- `+` asserts that the preceding expression (in our case, the character class) must match *one or more times*
- `$` Finally, this asserts that we're now at the end of the subject

When you're testing regular expressions, you'll likely find a tool like [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) helpful. This allows you to see your regular expression match (or fail to match) your sample data in real time as you write it.

Comment: `.-_` means `\x2e-\x5f`, I.E a range like `a-z`

Comment: also, if you want to explain regexes element by element, you should rather use [free-spacing mode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/freespacing.html) and `#` comments within the regex. it's much more readable and can be copied into the OP's code along with all the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the specific tip regarding the `-` being last in the class. I've been puzzling for quite a while on why my expression was mismatching.

Comment: @Esailija what does supposed to be the range between `.` and `_`? I think there is no range in a real example, or is?

Comment: What about `[A-z]`?

Answer (score 6):

Check out the basics of regular expressions in [a tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). All it requires is two [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and a [repeated](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
^[a-zA-Z ._-]*$
```

If you use the case-insensitive modifier, you can shorten this to

```
^[a-z ._-]*$
```

Note that the space is significant (it is just a character like any other).

Comment: That limits it to ASCII! In general you want something like `^[\p{Upper}\p{Lower} ._-]*$` or `^[\p{Letter} ._-]*$`.

Comment: @MRAB generally yes, but that is not supported by all regex flavors (and we don't know the flavor used by the OP's). plus, he might not even support unicode input. and finally, the OP should learn the basics of regex first, before thinking about unicode properties.

Comment: What about `[A-z]`?

Comment: @AaronFranke that includes all ASCII characters between `Z` and `a`, specifically ``[\]^_` ``